# Running a SOQL from Apex Class Apex.Class.ClassName.FunctionName: line 111 Is causing high CPU Utlilzation

Tags: apex, soql, cpulimit

I have a function in which I query on Lead object and we have around 1 million leads.
When we query on leads, we add a clause using a formula field in the query.
for example,

```
[SELECT Id, Name, Status FROM Lead WHERE Standard_Phone__c='11234567890' LIMIT 1];
```

The `Standard_Phone__c` is a complex formula field thus, it cannot be indexed in Salesforce.

Is there any solution I can use to optimize the query so that it should minimize the number of records being traversed?

Comment: Are you able to add any other indexed fields to the WHERE clause so that your filter does not have to run on the entire data set?
How complex is the formula field?

Comment: And what is the context of the code/logic around this query? Is it within a trigger context, scheduled job, etc.

Comment: I recommend adding a trigger to normalize the phone number into an e.164 format and then making that field an external Id so it is indexed. Of course, you would need to backfill all your legacy Leads

Comment: @cropredy We can not afford to update all the leads in the system, it will be very risky as the instance have more than a million leads. Also, there are various triggers and field updates

Comment: @KrisGoncalves The query is under Aura context. It's not being called from any asynchronous apex or triggers.

Comment: this is why, in our org, we gate all our automations and triggers with a test to see if the running user is a "data migration user" so we can safely do these backfills. Otherwise, you'll need to include in your query filters that are indexed, like `CreatedDate`. Do you need to look back till the dawn of time for such a Lead or only leads created in the last 90 days, for example?

Comment: We provide SMS services, when we receive a message for a lead then we try to query the lead details through phone numbers so that we can show the specific bell notification to the user in Salesforce. It can be any lead from the instance.

Comment: well, you could use an optimistic querying strategy with fallback - query on Leads created in last 90 days and if not found, put the SMS number into a custom object row and have a every 4 hour batch job read all leads and match against the deferred SMS number.

Comment: @cropredy thanks for the awesome suggestion. We do store all the messages into a custom object and we can use that to get the related object Id and then we can query using the ID. Can you please post your solution to this post, so that I can mark it as a solution? Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

I created an app, Unleash Your Formula, to deal with such a use case https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N4V00000DVyH4UAL. The app simply copies and syncs a formula field to a regular text (or other data type) field.

Simply install the app, create an indexed text field, map the formula field to this new field and query by this new field.